# string reverse problem

Tags: java

i have written a java program to reverse the contents of the string and display them.

here is the code..

```
import java.util.*;
class StringReverse
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string to be reversed :");
        String input = in.next();  
        char[] myArray = new char[input.length()];
        myArray = input.toCharArray();
        int frontPos=0,rearPos=(myArray.length)-1;
        char tempChar;
        while(frontPos!=rearPos)
        {
            tempChar=myArray[frontPos];
            myArray[frontPos]=myArray[rearPos];
            myArray[rearPos]=tempChar;
            frontPos++;
            rearPos--;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("The reversed string is : ");
        for(char c : myArray)
        {
            System.out.print(c);
        }

    }
}
```

Now the program works fine for strings of length greater than or equal to 5. But if I give a string of length 4 as input, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which line does the exception get thrown?

Comment: Nope, that algorithm surely won't work for all strings with length greater or equal 5 (a hint: for 50%) - and will actually work correct for strings smaller than 5. Just think the execution of your algorithm through for a few testcases and you'll certainly see the problem yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue isn't that the input is of length 4, but that the length 4 is an *even* length, so your stopping condition never hits. That is, `frontpos` *never* equals `rearpos` for even length strings.

You should instead just make sure that `frontpos` is *less* than `rearpos`, changing `while(frontPos!=rearPos)` to `while(frontPos < rearPos)` should clear things up.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed the `while (condition)` and worked like a charm..

Answer (score 3):

Would probably be easier to write with only one counter.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  char temp = myArray[i];
  myArray[i] = myArray[myArray.length - i - 1];
  myArray[myArray.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
String reversed = new String(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making the logic so complicated. It can easily be done as:

```
char temp[] = new char[str.length()];
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = str.length()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        temp[k] = str.charAt(i);
        k++;
    }
System.out.println(new String(temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverse(String str)
{
    String rev = " ";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        rev = str.charAt(i) + rev;
    }
    return rev.trim();
}
```

Input:

```
December
```

Output:

```
rebmeceD
```